# Trouble writing a select query

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, ado.net

I want to select table data in my page. Kindly provide a solution for my select query.

This is my code:

```
con.Open()
cmd = New SqlCommand("select name from wq where id='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
While dr.Read
    TextBox2.Text = dr(0)
End While
dr.Close()
con.Close()
```

Comment: That looks like vb.net, not c#? Also, what's not working about it?

Comment: it's vb -_- . Please change your tag

Comment: Can we say, "SQL injection"?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: if needed to set value of textbox, use execute scalar instead of data reader or data table as value of only one column is needed.
Also, specify top 1 in query.

Comment: @Satyajit He is trying to use `while loop` so specifying `top 1` will retrieve unwanted results, :P

Answer (score -4, accepted):

It looks like vb code if you want c# code then use following code

```
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select name from wq where id='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);
    con.Open();
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();
    TextBox2.Text = dr[0].ToString();
    dr.Close();
    con.Close();
```

Comment: -1 for `New`, I guess you just copy pasted his code...

Comment: Can we say, "SQL injection"?

Comment: Also missing some `()`, and you don't check the read was sucessful...

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi If i just do copy and paste, how the dr(0) changed to dr[0].ToString();

Comment: @Venkat That's obvious, you changed and forgot to change the `New` to `new`, you have not even changed it now...

Comment: Please make use of execute scalar and add null checking while accessing value from the data reader. Otherwise it will give null reference error when no rows is returned by the query.

Also, sanitize the user inputed value in the textbox to prevent sql injection.