# How can I use a data reader in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am learning to use select query for my program .

This my code.

```
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select id from qw where name='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);
SqlDataReader dr = SqlDataReader();
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dr.read();
TextBox2.Text = dr[0].Tostring();
dr.close();
con.Close();
```

it show this error message

'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: @Arran you cannot create new instance of SqlDataReader. Check this for more http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson04

Comment: @NitinVarpe, well spotted - removed :) (teaches me about not looking at the question properly)

Comment: **[Dupe accounts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560125/trouble-writing-a-select-query)**

Answer (score 3):

That's the correct code that match yours above

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(.......))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select id from qw where name=@name", con))
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text);
    using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
       if(dr.read())
       {
           TextBox2.Text = dr[0].ToString();
       }
    }
}
```

Things changed:

- Use the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) around disposable objects (so they are
  disposed and closed when no more needed and also in case of
  exceptions)
- Use a parameterized query instead of string concatenation ([read
  about Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work))
- Get the reader executing `ExecuteReader` method of your command
- Check if the reader returns something